# Why do some multiselect parameters show the selected values, and some don't

Tags: reporting-services

I'm at a loss here.  I've got a report with multiselect parameters, and everything works, but what I can't figure out it is why some of the parameters show the selected values and some don't.  Take the following example:

[image]

Parameters with their dropdowns:

[image]   [image]

Notice Par1 shows the selected values "00400", "00540", etc in the dropdown, but Par2 doesn't show anything, even though all items are selected. Both parameters properties are pretty much identical just with different queries.  I've used the same dataset for the Available Values and Default Values, each dataset doesn't return any nulls.  Anything else I can check?  My users will be confused by this I'm sure.

Thanks!

Comment: I think we would need to see the queries behind those parameters to troubleshoot this

Comment: Are the data types the same between the two parameters?